# Can download files (without file name or extension), but unable to see them?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the Google Drive API to generate a downloadable link for a file that looks like this:
`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{file_id}?access_token={access_token}&alt=media`

The problem is files are being downloaded without name and without extension.

If I add the extension manually after the file downloads it still works, but it's bad to tell my users they have to do that every time, and the user would have to know which extension the file actually has.

If I call `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/?access_token={access_token}`

I can't see the files I've uploaded... I think it could be a problem related to having access to the files' metadata, but I did authorize the auth.files.metadata scope.

I generate the access token using the refresh token and obtained the refresh token from the Oauth Playground... I'm confident I used the proper credentials for my application, but I could triple-check if someone suggests this could be the problem.

What can I do to debug this?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. What do you want to do by requesting to ``https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/?access_token={access_token}``? 2. Can I ask you about the detail information of ``I can't see the files I've uploaded``?

Comment: 1. I want the users of my application to be able to download a file on my Google Drive from their browser. I do this by calling this endpoint with the file id, when I don't add the file id, Google is supposed to return a list of my files, and it responds, but my files aren't there.

2. This endpoint lists the files that are visible to me, but my files aren&#39;t there. If I remove the alt=media from the URL, I get a json saying &quot;404&quot;.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If no file ID is used, the error occurs. And ``https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/`` is the method of files.list. When you want to download files, please use the files.get method and files.export method. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads For example, if you want to retrieve file ID from filename, you can retrieve it using ``q`` of files.list method. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref Is my understanding for your reply correct?

Comment: Not really. As I said in my comment, I am already using the files.get method, the point is that the files.get method is downloading the file without it's name and without it's extension and, for some odd reason, my files are not listed when I use the files.list method... in fact, if I use the files.get method without the "alt=media" tag, I get a 404 error.

Comment: I apologize for my poor English skill.